# Почему я не могу задать относительный размер кнопки XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

Я только начал знакомится с WPF. Пытаюсь задать относительный размер кнопки, но получаю ошибку: Строку "*" невозможно преобразовать в значение Length.  LocalSI MainWindow.xaml 11

Вот код:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="A" Width="*"/>
    <Button Content="B" Width="*"/>
</Grid>
```

Тем не менее, я могу задавать относительную длину колонок:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Почему я могу сделать это для колонок, но не могу для кнопок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё просто:

[свойство `Width`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.width) кнопки наследуется от базового класса `FrameworkElement` и имеет тип `double` — т. е. число и ничего больше (в `double` есть, конечно, специальные значения `NaN`, но это тут ни при чем);

[свойство `ColumnDefinition.Width`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.columndefinition.width) имеет специальный [тип `GridLength`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en/dotnet/api/system.windows.gridlength), который содержит в себе помимо числового значения `double` еще и специальное значение `GridUnitType`, которое в свою очередь указывает на тип значения: абсолютный или относительный.

XAML же умеет преобразовывать строки в значения типа `GridLength`, для этого он неявно использует специальный класс конвертера [`GridLengthConverter`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en/dotnet/api/system.windows.gridlengthconverter).

Для получения значения `double` из строки XAML тоже использует конвертер, но не тот, а другой — [`LengthConverter`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en/dotnet/api/system.windows.lengthconverter) и он не понимает звездочки и прочие спецсимволы.

С другой стороны, такой возможности для кнопок (и прочих контролов) нет еще и по той причине, что это бессмысленно. На самом деле кнопки ничего не знают о контролах их окружающих, они могут только изъявить желание получить выравнивание по какому-то краю или по центру или быть растянутыми на все доступное пространство, но компоновкой занимаются **только** панели (и вполне себе панель может проигнорировать желание контрола если оно ей не нравится). Панель знает о всех ее дочерних элементах и, поэтому, может устанавливать им значения ширины и длины в зависимости от соседних. И именно поэтому *очень важно* знать стандартные панели и уметь ими пользоваться.

Так что да, если вы хотите иметь пару кнопок одинаковой ширины, вы должны поместить их в один и тот же Grid (или UniformGrid) и указать именно панели, что вы хотите иметь ячейки в сетке одинаковой ширины (в UniformGrid такое поведение присутствует всегда и не меняется).